# Using jquery to concanate html data element

Tags: jquery

I have several objects on my page that I can identify by div.lightchk, I want to concatenate the contents of the data element data-x10 into a variable so it looks like "a1.a2.a3.b1.b2.b3"

using jquery whats the best way of doing this??  the . is puzzling me as I don't want the last entry to have it.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = '';
$('div.lightchk').each(function () {
    var x10 = $(this).data('x10');
    if (x10) {
        if (result.length) {
            result += '.'; // Add a dot first on every concat but the first

        result += x10;
    }
});
```

Let me know if you want me to elaborate on the code, I think it's pretty self-explaining :)

Comment: thanks Hans much appreciated but I dont want the dot on the last x10 value.

Comment: In your example, you do. Mind you, this code adds the dot _before_ the x10.